# work with the value from tkmessagebox in R

Tags: r

```
require(tcltk)
msgBox1 <- tkmessageBox(title = "Trial", message = "Run code?", icon = "info", type = "yesno")

msgBox1


if (msgBox1 == 'yes')
{
print('yesterday')
}
```

Error in msgBox1 == "yes" :
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

How can I access the yes/no value for comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value can be obtained with `tclvalue`:

```
if (tclvalue(msgBox1) == 'yes')
{
   print('yesterday')
 }
#[1] "yesterday"
```

Another option is to convert `msgBox1` to character :

```
if (as.character(msgBox1) == 'yes')
{
   print('yesterday')
 }
#[1] "yesterday"
```